# Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any function.

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

1. Show that for any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$.
2. Show that for any set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $B \supseteq f(f^{-1}(A))$.

How to write the formal procedures for these kind of proofs?

Comment: The second inclusion should be$\;B\supset f\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)$

Comment: For 1), let $x \in A$.  We want to show that $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$.  So what does it mean for $x$ to belong to $f^{-1}(f(A))$?

Comment: Suppose $f$ not bijective. Then $\nexists f^{-1}:A\subseteq (f^{-1}\circ f)(A)$ and $\nexists f^{-1}:B\supset (f\circ f^{-1})(B)$. You should have the condition that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: @user474330 That is not correct.  In this context, $f^{-1}(B)$ (where $B$ is a set) is the preimage of that set.  Thus $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is the collection of all values $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) = y$.  Note that it is a set, not a single element.

Comment: @Garmekain No, here $f^{-1} \colon \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{R}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ doesn't mean the inverse function to $f$ - it denotes the function mapping $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ to its preimage under $f$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you for that correction/clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with what you know. What is $f(A)$? What is $f^{-1}(B)$, where $A,B \subseteq \mathbb R$.

Once you've figured that out, start with $a \in A$. We want to show that $a \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. So we need to find some $b \in f(A)$ such that $f(a) = b$. What could $b$ be?

Part two follows a very similar routine.